# Confirm Dialog before submitting form in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, popup, dialog

I have a button which will show a confirm dialog when I click. I use this http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/ Plugin. When I click the button, a pop up appears. But there's nothing happening even when I click on Yes.

```
         $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#btnDelete').confirm({
                title: "Delete confirmation",
                text: "Are you sure?",
                confirm: function (button) {
                    //$(button).submit();
                    return true;
                },
                cancel: function (button) {
                    return false;
                },
                confirmButton: "Yes I am",
                cancelButton: "No",
                post: true
            });

        });
```

My ASP.NET code looks like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server"  />
```

Note: There is already code behind function which handles Click event of btnDelete.

Comment: instead of `ID` , have you tried `CssClass` name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem in a different way with Bootstrap modals. 
More examples are here.. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

The modified delete button.. 
When I click on this 'Delete' button, it calls a model named "deleteModal".

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" 
            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" />
```

DeleteModal-Popup has Yes/No buttons. I've registered a click event on the "Yes" button.

```
<!--Popup Ja-Button-->
<asp:Button ID="btnDeleteConfirm" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server"/>
```

That's it. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is [your `ClientIDMode` isn't set to `Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Therefore your HTML item does not have an id of `btnDelete`. It's probably `container_container_contatin_etc._btnDelete`

If you change your selector from

```
$('#btnDelete')
```

to

```
$('input[id$=btnDelete]')
```

It'll probably work. Without your HTML though this is a bit of a guess.

[Jquery selector here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)